# <?php if ($is_blog): ?>

Tags: theming

In my page.tpl.php, I want to add a line only for my blog page similar to how I see elements applied only to the front page.

```
 <?php if ($is_front): ?>

 <?php if ($is_blog): ?>
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me the correct PHP to target the blog page?

Answer (score 3):

`$is_blog` is not a valid variable in page.tpl.php. You can refer to the [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7) documentation for more details on which variables are available.

In a situation like this, you will most likely want to implement [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) in your theme's template.php file in order to make additions to be page template.
Depending on whether you want this to apply on an individual blog entry's page or a blog listing page, the exact implementation will vary.

Another option would be to duplicate your page.tpl.php file and rename it to page--blog.tpl.php and make your additions there. Another simple solution would be to create a custom block that only displays on blog pages.

Comment: Since I only wanted to implement a different container for the blog than the regular page, I thought it would be smile enough to avoid having a completely different tpl page but I guess that is simple enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sheena has the proper answer, but just to add a touch to clarify, if you want to have a `$is_blog` variable accessible to all your templates, you will need to add a  `theme_preprocess_page` function in your `page.tpl.php`. 
 Something maybe similar to this:

```
function <yourthemeName>_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["q"]);
    // check if we are on blog page 
    if (check_is_blog($path)) {
      $variables['is_blog'] = true;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps. Credits go to sheena_d.

Comment: Where are you getting `check_is_blog()` from?

Comment: Oh, my bad that would be a custom function. I should have mentionned that in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tpl.php file for every node type. To figure out the correct name of the tpl.php file install the [Theme Developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) and simply point and click on your blog (or whatever you want to style differently).

Comment: This is also a way to theme content types, I go for functions if I know I am the only one working on the project. If it's a team effort, we usually will slap up templates.